# Update second row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table called `ps_cart_product` with the following structure:

```
>desc ps_cart_product;
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id_cart              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| id_product           | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| id_address_delivery  | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| id_shop              | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| id_product_attribute | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| quantity             | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| date_add             | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This table has several rows. I'd like to update the second row with `id_cart=625 AND id_product=63`. 
If I query:

```
> select * from ps_cart_product where id_cart=625 and id_product=63;
+---------+------------+---------------------+---------+----------------------+----------+---------------------+
| id_cart | id_product | id_address_delivery | id_shop | id_product_attribute | quantity | date_add            |
+---------+------------+---------------------+---------+----------------------+----------+---------------------+
|     625 |         63 |                   0 |       1 |                  279 |        2 | 2015-05-18 10:29:23 |
|     625 |         63 |                   0 |       1 |                  275 |        1 | 2015-05-18 10:28:55 |
+---------+------------+---------------------+---------+----------------------+----------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I would like to execute an SQL UPDATE statement like:

```
UPDATE ps_cart_product
   SET id_product_attribute = 280
 WHERE id_cart = 625
   AND id_product = 63
   AND XXXXXXXX
```

I don't know what to write in `XXXXXXXX` to update only the second row. I cannot use the volues of `id_product_attribute` , `quantity` nor `date_add` to filter the `UPDATE` statement, as I've got no control of their value.

Comment: What defines 2nd row  `date_add`?

Comment: just the order given in the `SELECT` clause

Comment: no the order in the returned data has no meaning unless its explicitly order by some column. So you need to have some order by clause to determine the  2nd row.

Comment: In truth my order is `id_cart` i `id_product`, but it is equal for these two rows.

Comment: Simply use the Primary Key to access a specific row. Oh, but there's no PK. Ouch.

Comment: This is the problem. I know I can add an autoincrement key, but I'd like to not modify the schema.

Comment: Autoincrement is not a real key, it doesn't prevent inserting the same row over and over again. Usually there's a *line_number* added or you might use *date_add* to get a `PK(id_cart, line_number)`

Comment: @dnoeth, but I want to be able to repeat lines!

Comment: You got no control over the value of `date_add` but you know the value after running the SELECT. So simply use `WHERE id_cart = 625
   AND id_product = 63
   AND date_add = '2015-05-18 10:28:55'`

Comment: But both lines could have the same `date_add`...

Comment: Then you need to add more columns to the WHERE, hopefully the combination of all columns is unique.

Comment: Ok. Finally I added an auto_increment id

Answer (score 0):

If you can introduce an auto increment `id` field, then i hope that can solve your problem.